# Using In-memory Database With Hibernate tutorial how to execute?

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

I'm new in Java and Hibernate as well. I'm following this tutorial @ http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/09/03/hibernate-4-using-in-memory-database-with-hibernate/

I managed to compile the code and understood the concept as well. But the problem is that I don't know how to execute the code to debug some stuff. When I start app as java application in  eclipse. I have a long list to of option. But I don't see my actual test class to run. So How to run it and debug this app? Also I tried this @ https://gist.github.com/twasink/2881461. Same is issue. No idea how to run.

Please check the screen shoot of eclipse list while:-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `main()` method in `TestHibernate.java`. Use it.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial that you are following is maven project.
Try creating a simple maven project in eclipse and move the required artifacts to thelocation
as specified in the screenshot in the tutorial.
It will be a good learning curve to you.

As a hint use archetype as maven-archetypes-quickstart while creating maven project.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I think you didn't read my question correctly. I mentioned that I managed to compile the project. I just don't know how to execute it. Once I try to run as it brings list of app to execute. In the list my app is missing